# Show that $a^{bc}+b^{ca}+c^{ab}>2$ for $a,b,c\in(0,1)$

Tags: inequality, exponential-function, sum-of-squares-method

> Show that $a^{bc}+b^{ca}+c^{ab}>2$ for $a,b,c\in(0,1)$.

I have no idea how to attempt this exponential inequality and couldn't find the condition for equality. Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: I would try it for a=b=c and then try it with just one equality to get intuition.

Comment: @Alephnull But it leads to nowhere for me. How do I proceed?

Comment: If I knew I would tell you . A lot of these types of problems what you can do is hold one or more variables constant while screwing around with the other variables and show it doesn't decrease the function output; then you just have to show it is true for one value. You can have WLOG a<=b<=c due to symmetry.

Comment: @YuxiaoXie Can you share the source of this question? Am just curious and looking for sources of good problems

Comment: @grayQuant A friend gave it to me and so I don't know the source. Sorry. But if you're looking for good problems, AoPS is a good website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{x,y\}\subset(0,1)$.

Hence, by Bernoulli $\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^y=\left(1+\frac{1}{x}-1\right)^y\leq1+y\left(\frac{1}{x}-1\right)=\frac{x+y-xy}{x}$.

Id est, $\sum\limits_{cyc}a^{bc}\geq\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a}{a+bc-abc}$.

Thus, it remains to prove that $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a}{a+bc-abc}\geq2$, which is

$2a^2b^2c^2-2abc+1+\sum\limits_{cyc}(-2a^2b^2c+a^2bc+a^2b+a^2c-a^2)\geq0$ 0r

$$(1-a^2)(1-b^2)(1-c^2)+\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2b^2c^2-2a^2b^2c+a^2bc)+$$
$$+\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c-2a^2b^2)+\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(a^2b+a^2c-\frac{4}{3}abc\right)\geq0,$$
which is obvious because 
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c-2a^2b^2)=\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2(b-b^2)+a^2(c-c^2))\geq0,$$ 
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2b^2c^2-2a^2b^2c+a^2bc)=abc\sum\limits_{cyc}a(1-b)(1-c)\geq0$$ and
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(a^2b+a^2c-\frac{4}{3}abc\right)\geq\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(a^2b+a^2c-2abc\right)=\sum\limits_{cyc}c(a-b)^2\geq0$$
Done!

Comment: Dear @Yuxiao Xie What do you think about my proof? Something is not true?